# Right align a specific column separated by spaces

Tags: vim, alignment, tabular

Example:

```
Monte Bianco 4.807 France/Italy
Monte Rosa 4.634 Italy/Switzerland
Dom 4.545 Switzerland/Italy
Weisshorn 4.505 Switzerland
Cervino (Matterhorn) 4.478 Italy/Switzerland
Suphan Dagi 4.434 Turkey
```

I'm trying to create 2 new menu options (in menu.vim):

- Align right 1st column
- Align right last column

I can't find out how to align right only the first, only the last column or a specific column in the middle of my table.

```
Monte Bianco 4.807              France/Italy
Monte Rosa 4.634           Italy/Switzerland
Dom 4.545                  Switzerland/Italy
Weisshorn 4.505                  Switzerland
Cervino (Matterhorn) 4.478 Italy/Switzerland
Suphan Dagi 4.434                     Turkey
```

I know I can use this to align right the latest column

```
Tabular /^\(.\{-}\s\{1,}\)\{1,}/l0l0r0
```

but what I want to find out is how to find the latest align parameter before the end of line
(p.e. in above example "Spaces") and align right all text after this (without counting the number of columns).

Is this possible?

And I have no idea at all how to align right only the first column or a specific column.

Comment: How do you define a column? If they are space-separated then does “Monte Bianco” span over 2 columns?

Comment: @Benoit, monte bianco must be 2 different columns "monte" and "bianco" My idea is to add spcaces where I need the columns and then do above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to right align the first whitespace-separated column leaving the rest
of them aligned to the left, use the following `:Tabular` command,

```
:Tab/^\S*\s\+\zs/r1l0l0
```

Similarly, to right align the last column, run

```
:Tab/\s\@<!\ze\s\+\S*$/l1l0r0
```

If column separators must have, say, at least two space characters, modify the
commands as follows.

```
:Tab/\(\s\{2,}.*\)\@<!\s\{2,}\zs/r1l0l0
```

and

```
:Tab/\s\@<!\ze\s\{2,}\(.*\s\{2,}\)\@!/l1l0r0
```

Comment: Thank you very much ib. What would be the formulas if I want not to do the right align at the first whitespace separator but at the first 2 whitespaces seperators? (jumping over separators with only 1 whitespace)

Comment: @Remonn:  I added the commands corresponding to that case.  To change the minimum number of spaces that column separators must have, substitute `2` with an appropriate number.